# Tripping Inline GFI Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair

We are working on an "inline" GFI Circut (has 4 or 5 outlets on the GFI Circut).  When we use a tester to test for 110 (Red prob to hot side of socket and Black prob to ground at box) it pops the GFI on the outlet.  After every reset (reset always stays in) and a tool is plugged into the outlet, the plug doesn't respond.  We test for 110 again, and the GFI pops out again (As soon as the probe makes contact, the GFI pops).

Thank you!

Kim

Comment: Your probe is leaking current from hot to ground, essentially your meter is a ground-fault. What type of meter are you using?

Comment: Tester101 is on the right track. I recommend a dedicated outlet tester; it will diagnose common wiring issues and let you test gfis as well. They are cheap

Comment: What is the question? To prevent the fault measure hot to neutral.